# SFTP Error: open for write: permission denied

Tags: centos, permissions, sftp

I have created a user and a group only for SFTP and when I try to transfer a file with Filezilla in `/var/www` I have this error:

```
Open for write: permission denied
```

I have configured `sshd_config` like this :

```
#Subsystem Sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Group sftp_only Match
ChrootDirectory /var/www
ForceCommand internal-sftp
X11Forwarding No
AllowTcpForwarding No
```

/var/www and sub directories are `chown root:root` and `chmod 755`

SELinux is disabled.

Any idea ?

Comment: The chroot directory should not be /var/www, rather /var/www/sftp or some such which you then give the proper read/write permissions to for the SFTP user/group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The permission of `/var/www` does not permit the chrooted-user to create files in it.
That is correct and by design.
You must create a folder inside of `/var/www` with the proper rights of the user.

`/var/www` can not be writeable for the user.